# Why doesn't the C++ standard library provide constexpr versions of the cmath functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, std

We have `constexpr` functions since C++11, and they have been getting less restricted since with every new standard (14, 1z).

Yet, the most obvious functions in STL which could be made `constexpr`, the `cmath`/`math.h` functions, still have no `constexpr` version in any standard library implementation AFAIK.

Is this just in the backlog of the C++ standard, or is there any other reason why we still don't have `constexpr` versions of these functions?

Comment: I don't the `math` tag is appropriate here, at least according to the tag wiki. I suggest you remove it.

Comment: Because `cmath` and `math.h` are C headers. Furthermore the implementation of those functions requires type punning which is not allowed in `constexpr` functions.

Comment: Why are you asking again, when you noticed that the 1st version of your question didn't fly well? Instead of asking about 3rd party resource, you're _off topic_ asking for opinions now.

Comment: @DeiDei "Because `cmath` and `math.h` are C headers" - that's irrelevant to the question, STL can have a new header with similar `constexpr` versions of the functions. Regarding type punning, that's interesting, I suppose not all the functions require it,  and I guess all *could* be implemented without it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not asking for an opinion, but for facts, if any are available.

Comment: @Danra Well, nowadays you may receive _alternative facts_ as answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's true, though to me, implementing `constexpr` versions of the `cmath` functions looks like an EASY D

Comment: @Danra: I have tried implementing some of the functions `sin` `cos`,... as `constexpr`, and while it was not impossible it did pose a big challenge at least using c++11. A big part of the issue is that it would be hard to guarantee that the algorithms that they could use to generate a `constexpr` version of the functions would be of the same quality as the runtime versions. And that doesn't even account for the need for error handling...

Comment: I disagree with the question being closed. "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." - actually facts and references are mostly what I'm looking for, not opinions.

Comment: Vote to reopen. The "backlog of the C++ standard" not only exists, it's public as well. Whether they refer to `constexpr` versions of `<cmath>` functions equally is a matter of fact, not opinion. Please do not close questions about the ISO standardization process if you personally aren't familiar with it.

Comment: [Great timing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0533r0.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It hasn't been standardized yet. An initial [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0533r0.pdf) was submitted just last week, but only covering utility and linear operations and not any transcendental functions. Math is hard and floating-point math is complicated. For example, implementations don't allow overflows to infinity in `constexpr`, but this isn't yet clearly standardized.

The compiler's `constexpr` interpreter would have to special-case the math library interface, since unlike the rest of the standard library, it can't see its implementation.

GCC does offer constant evaluation of math functions as a nonconforming extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "The compiler's constexpr interpreter would have to special-case the math library interface, since it can't see its implementation."? Obviously the *existing* math.h/cmath functions can't be made constexpr (since among other things they set errno) so a different header would be required anyway to implement the constexpr versions.

Comment: @Danra Putting math function implementations into the header and recompiling them every time is a non-starter. Constant interpretation requires its own, fake compile-time implementation. Until the language gains a feature for such things (and there is discussion of just that), it would be a special case.

Comment: Note, though, that `constexpr` doesn't guarantee compile-time success. Constant math can bail out on overflow or `errno`, which is just what GCC does.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Does that mean all constexpr functions in the STL are treated as such special cases?

Comment: @Danra No. The `constexpr` parts of the standard library have their implementation in the headers. That's what would make the math a special case. (And in GCC, it's already a special case, implemented in their C constant folding engine and utilized for C++ `constexpr`.)

Comment: "nor even proposed for standardization" is [no longer true](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0533r0.pdf).

Comment: The proposal mentions Clang also actually supports constexpr math functions via its builtins. e.g. the `pow` function which I was specifically interested in is implemented as `constexpr`-ish `__builtin_pow`.

Comment: @Danra Interesting. Looking around a bit, I soon found [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3513) though which suggests that Clang's QOI might not be the same.

Comment: I wonder how floating-point rounding mode interacts with `constexpr` math functions?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin C++ doesn't specify `pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`, but maybe it should.

Comment: @Danra Sorry, I don't understand. What's "reinterpretation"? You can also submit an edit to the answer…

Comment: @Danra [Here you go](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/NErPRYCz3ZU). The first post in the thread is good but then it gets sidetracked… C'est la vie.

Comment: Can you link to documentation regarding the GCC extensions?

Comment: There's [a newer proposal, P1383R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1383r0.pdf), which does consider transcendental functions.